# how to extract logs from VRLI to fluentd

Tags: vmware, fluentd

I'm searching to the way of extract logs from VRLI to fluentd.

Ability that fluentd will pull from VRLI or VRLI will push somehow it to fluentd.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found that VRLI support event forward with protocol option `Ingestion API`.

After definition of this event forward to fluend with below configuration I start to get relevant events in my fluentd

```
<source>
  @type http
  port 24231
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match api.v1.messages.ingest.**>
    @type stdout
</match>
```